# Pseudo :focus-within not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, button, safari, focus

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    #my-button:focus-within {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="my-button" tabindex="0">item2</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Once pressed, the color should switch to red. Works in Chrome and Firefox, Safari (tested on version 15.6.1) as always makes problems.

But what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, :focus-within cannot be applied to a button in Safari. But this works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    #my-li:focus-within > #my-button {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li id="my-li" tabindex="0">
      <button id="my-button">item2</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```